# Hibernate throws NoResultException even though the record exists in DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final, hibernate 4.0` with Rest-easy framework.Issue is after persisting the record in DB immediately an update call is fired to update/insert child entity of the persisted object.

So I am using `em.find(record.class, primary key(long))` method to get the persisted parent record and checking null. If the parent record is not null then inserting/updating into child record.

It is working fine in local, but when I do load testing the parent record is coming as null even though the parent object is present in DB. Any idea ?

Below is the code snapshot:

```
//persisting record in one API call
entityManager.persist(record);

//Finding record 
    Record record = entityManager.find(Record.class, recordId);
        if (record != null) {
            //Fetch child entity
            Hibernate.initialize(record.getRecordsettings());
            Hibernate.initialize(record.getRecordstate());
        }
        return record;
    }
```

I have tried with `em.refresh()`, but it is not solving the problem.

Comment: please post your snapshot properly

Comment: Are all these happening in the same TX?

Comment: No. Persisting object in one transaction and update is happening in another transaction. Both transactions are happening in fraction of milliseconds interval. only for some records this issue is raising

Answer (score 0):

> Persisting object in one transaction and update is happening in
>   another transaction. Both transactions are happening *in fraction of
>   milliseconds interval. only for some records this issue is raising*

This may be occurring because of the minimal interval between the create & update.
If you can, try creating and updating on two separate threads. And join the update thread to ensure it waits for the create thread to complete. Reply with your results.

Also, refer this post and check to see if your update fires before your insert completes:

[How to log the response time for insert & update query in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355669/how-to-log-the-response-time-for-insert-and-update-query-in-hibernate)

P.S.> Don't have comment privileges yet, so posting as an answer.