# How to log the response time for insert and update query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the hibernate version 5.0.1.I have enabled hibernate.generate.statistics=true and log4j.logger.org.hibernate.stat=debug.The statistics is generated for select query alone.I need the statistics for insert and update query as well.

As of now we are logging the time difference between the before and after execution time for insert and update queries.

Please help me to get clarified on this.

Comment: There is no setting for insert and update query for this. You can manually write log statement at the start and end of your method is the only way to get execution times.

Comment: Yes. We are now doing the same method that you have suggested. I thought that there might be some way .Thanks alot for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look in below link, this might help you regarding hibernate configuration to activate hibernate performance logging.

[Activate Hibernate Statistics To Analyze Performance](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-activate-hibernate-statistics-to-analyze-performance-issues/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at a hibernate interceptor:

```
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        LOG.debug("start ...");
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        LOG.debug("start ...");
        super.afterTransactionCompletion(tx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add lines:

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

to application's `persistence.xml` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that JBoss doesn't use log4j by default. So if you ues JBOSS as application server, adding log4j.properties to ear won't help. Just try to add to jboss-logging.xml:

   `<logger category="org.hibernate">
     <level name="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>`